# Google Analytics - Single page web site - average visit duration

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I run this web site http://www.theloancalculator.org which is made of a single unique page.

However many actions are possible within the page, but all are pure javascript actions not leading to any other page.

What is the right approach to let Google Analytics properly evaluate the average visit duration ?

Google analytics currently displays a very low average visit duration which I believe to be wrong.

I was thinking about adding events, but I am not sure if that is the right approach, since I am going to be flooded with custom events if I trace each possible javascript action.

Answer (score 1):

Google can't track duration of visit unless users visit another page.  The click to another page is how they calculate time.  The average time on page in multi-page sites does not include the time spent on the last page visited, and is considered an exit.
Using events or the Google tag manager are the only options I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to call on javascript actions :
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);